# android gps cover long area

Tags: android

i'm using gps and i add some over lay points in the map so i want when my current location is ==  the over lay item remove the item ! the problem is the gps inaccuracy  and i may be in place near  the overlay item but not same longitude and lat. so i want to add area around the overlay item say a delta so the question is what the delta suppose to be for sure its cant be int or float what it should be to add it to my over lay item lang and latitude .
Thank in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please rephrase. And avoid the use of "it's urgent" - that's off-putting.

Comment: i guess its more than clear now Mr Michael 
thank

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with GPS on Android, but it seems to me that you should be able to calculate the distance from your current position to the overlay item and check if it is less than some acceptable threshold. This just takes a little vector math:

```
int XSquared = Math.pow(myPosition.x - Item.x, 2);
int YSquared = Math.pow(myPosition.y - Item.y, 2);
double distance = Math.sqrt(XSquared + YSquared);

if(distance < threshold)
   removeItem(item);
```

Obviously this is not what the code will actually look like, but I hope it will give you some idea as to what you need to do.

Comment: The only tweak I'd make is don't bother with Math.sqrt, test ((XSquared+YSquared) < (threshold*threshold)) instead. Squaring threshold (or just setting it to be squared) is faster than Math.sqrt. Feel free to edit in.

Comment: No - that's not correct. It takes no account of the convergence of lines of equal longitude at the poles. You would need to use the haversine formula to do it by spherical trigonometry. A better idea would be to use the Android method Location.distanceBetween().

Comment: @ nickT so  i write loc.distanceBetween() //loc is my current location , and what should be the distanceBetween( the overlay item) or what

Comment: See hyperlink below for arguments to the method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29

Comment: lol, I'm glad that there are people who know more about this than me, i was just trying to give the general idea. Good work!